# Get the guid of the elements grouped in an ifcgroup

Tags: ifc

Is there a function in the API of IFCJS to get the guid of the elements grouped in an ifcgroup?
for example, if I group a column with a wall

> `getElementsFromIfcGroup(guidGroup) ---> return [guidWall, guidColumn]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the IFC schema, `IfcGroup` instances group elements together using an indirect relationship object called [IfcRelAssignsToGroup](https://standards.buildingsmart.org/IFC/RELEASE/IFC2x3/TC1/HTML/ifckernel/lexical/ifcrelassignstogroup.htm). This means that you can retrieve the elements contained within that group like this:

```
import { IFCRELASSIGNSTOGROUP as REL } from 'web-ifc';

async function getItemsOfGroup(modelID, groupID) {
  const manager = ifcLoader.ifcManager;
  const relIDs = await manager.getAllItemsOfType(modelID, REL);

  for(relID of groupsIDs) {
    const groupRel = await manager.getItemProperties(modelID, relID);
    if(groupRel.RelatingGroup.value === groupID) {
     return groupRel.RelatedObjects;
    }
  }

  return [];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

based on Antonio's answer, it looks like this:

```
    async function getItemsOfGroup(modelID, groupID) {
        const manager = viewer.IFC.loader.ifcManager
        // Get all ifcgroups
        const relIDs = await manager.getAllItemsOfType(modelID, IFCRELASSIGNSTOGROUP);
        let relID, relObj, props;
        var guIDs = [];
        for(relID of relIDs) {
            const groupRel = await manager.getItemProperties(modelID, relID);
            // Find the groupID
            if(groupRel.GlobalId.value === groupID) {
                // Search all related objects 
                for(relObj of groupRel.RelatedObjects) {
                    //get object properties 
                    props = await manager.getItemProperties(modelID, relObj.value);
                    //Add guid to array
                    guIDs[guIDs.length] = props.GlobalId.value;
                }
                return guIDs;
            }
        }
        return guIDs;
    }
```